# Is it possible to possible update registry values using a client side programming language

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, security, penetration-testing

I am new to penetration testing. My requirement is to update registry values from browser using a client side programming language like javascript. Is it possible?

Comment: Why downvote? He just asking for the possibility.

Answer (score 0):

No, JavaScript can't read / write arbitrary files to the hard disk, copy them or call programs. It does not have direct access to the operating system.

This is done for the security of users, so that an attacker could not use JavaScript to obtain personal data or somehow damage the user's computer.